# file_get_contents() for short urls

Tags: php, curl, short-url

`file_get_contents()` doesn't read data for short urls
Example:

- http://wp.me/pbZy8-1WM,
- http://bit.ly/d00E2C

Please help me in handle this. OR Is there any CURL function to handle above links?

Comment: @erisco if you use `file_get_contents` with a URL, it defers to cURL to get the data

Comment: According to http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php HTTP redirects are supported.

Comment: i tagged it in curl becoz can any one help me out by using curl functions.

Comment: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION is how you'd handle this with cUrl

Comment: @Rafe I don't believe that is entirely correct.

Comment: I think you'll find [it does](http://codepad.viper-7.com/EKtVm1).

Comment: Do you have [`allow_url_fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) on in `php.ini`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This in general works fine. If you find it doesn't do the right thing you can explicitly use a stream context:

```
$url = "http://bit.ly/d00E2C";
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('max_redirects' => 5)));
$val = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

should do it. No need to touch CURL for that.

Comment: I stole your contribution of `'max_redirects'`... not sure how I feel about that. Can you merge answers on Stackoverflow?

Comment: Since there is really no merge, my expectation is you get the answer given yours is more complete. Since we can't split the points...

Answer (score 4):

On my machine, I cannot replicate your problem; I receive the page as intended. However, should the issue be with the redirect, this may solve your problem.

```
<?php
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'follow_location' => 1,
        'max_redirects' => 20
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
echo file_get_contents('http://wp.me/pbZy8-1WM', false, $context);
```

I imagine there may be a directive that toggles redirect following, but I have not yet found it. I will edit my answer should I.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is using curl with CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION set to True:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://bit.ly/d00E2C");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```